# How do I combine Matomo Analytics with Google Tag Manager

Tags: google-tag-manager, matomo, google-analytics-4

What happens if I have a tag installed via Google Tag Manager but also have the tag script written into my pages? Is there a hierarchy of one script over another? I've tried installing both Google Analytics and Matomo Analytics 4 via Google Tag Manager and neither are reporting any real data. What happens if I add the Matomo script and/or Google Analytics tags directly into my web pages but leave their implementation via Google Tag Manager alone?  Pinterest seems perfectly happy, on the other hand, with tags installed the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Matomo doesn't typically conflict with GA. Both can be and should be deployed via a TMS, whether Matomo TMS or GTM.

Matomo actually is gracious enough to explain how to deploy their analytics via GTM here: https://matomo.org/faq/new-to-piwik/how-do-i-use-matomo-analytics-within-gtm-google-tag-manager/

In order to figure out why either Matomo or GA scripts don't work when deployed via GTM, you should use GTM preview and normal front-end debugging tools like the JS console and the Network tab.

The GTM Preview lets you know how your the GTM logic looks from the perspective of GTM, so whether the tag fired and the state of the variables at the time of firing.

The JS console lets you debug the actual code deployed and try things out on the fly.

Finally, the Network tab allows you to inspect the actual analytics calls to GA/Matomo.

Only after these things should you go to the respective analytics UIs and inspect the data, but it quickly becomes obsolete once you're familiar enough with the Network tab or have so very helpful Analytics debugging tools like the Adswerve browser extension.